# symfony 5 nelmio api doc no return

Tags: symfony5, nelmioapidocbundle

first of all sorry for my bad english.

I want to use NelmioApiDoc for my api, for the installation and configuration i have no problems and my route return this result :
[nemlio return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIwvu.png)

The is when I try to insert annotation to my controller, nothing change, the page have no change.
My controller :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotEncodableValueException;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Model;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Security;
use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;
/**
 * Class ApiProductController
 *
 */
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/api/products/showAll", name="productsShow")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @OA\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="Returns the products of an user",
     *     @OA\JsonContent(
     *        type="array",
     *        @OA\Items(ref=@Model(type=Product::class))
     *     )
     * )
     * @OA\Parameter(
     *     name="order",
     *     in="query",
     *     description="The field used to order products",
     *     @OA\Schema(type="string")
     * )
     * @OA\Tag(name="product")
     * @Security(name="Bearer")
     */
    public function showAll()
    { ... }
```

if you have a response to my, I take ! thanks all

Comment: Maybe remove this `@Method({"GET"})` and add this `@Route("/api/products/showAll", name="productsShow", methods={"GET"})`

Comment: did you check your nelmio_api_doc.yaml?
Can you post your configuration?